# adding a border for navigation menu bar

Tags: html, css

i want to add border right for each navigation menu .. the problem i happent is i don't want 100% border . need a gap top and border. and i need click functionaly for complete div. i try like this way

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px red solid;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

i don't want that red border with 100% height. just need a gap top and botoom...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Use pseudo-element `:after` for this.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  position:relative;
}
li a::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  height: 22px;
  width: 1px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```